# How to get the total iteration count for data provider

Tags: java, selenium, testng, dataprovider

I have a data provider which return 2d (data taken from the excel) and pass this to @test.

Through automation I want to activate  some user and after performing particular action agin de activate those users.

So the action instructions are fetch from the excel through data provider.De activation of the user should be done after the data provider's to the last iteration.

The excel data is dynamic .so is there any way to find out the data provider total row or final iteration

Data provider(name)
Code to return 2d

@test(data provider name)

Do the action 
(If it reach final iteration 
De activate ).  Is there any way for

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 2d array,  then you can do like this

```
int[][] example = new int[4][4];

for(int i=0; i<example.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<example[i].length; j++) {

           if (i==example.length-1 && j == example[i].length-1){

                   //do your stuff , this is last iteration      
              }

        }
```